# how to continuous bouncing uibutton between two points

Tags: ios, uibutton, core-animation, quartz-core

I'm new to iPhone developing,am using folling code to animate my UIButton it's animating perfectly but when i click the button the action not firing. plese help me out from this.

```
 [UIButton animateWithDuration:3.0
                          delay:0.0f
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations: ^(void){
                         CGPoint p = Mybutton.center;
                         p.y += 100;
                         Mybutton.center = p;

                     }
                     completion:NULL];
```

Comment: This doesn't show us how you're creating the button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this code in the button action or viewDidLoad? Try this one :

```
   - (IBAction)buttonAnimation:(id)sender {
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
animation.duration = .3;
animation.repeatCount = 5;
animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:yourButton.center];
animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(yourButton.center.x, yourButton.center.y-30)];
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[yourButton.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];}
```

You should put it in the button action.
Hope it helps